# five3d local3dtoglobal

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

I am trying to use the Five3d package to draw a sprite in 3d and animate it then create a shape on the root of the app and overlay it over the sprite in 3d as it moves. I have tried everything to get it to work but can't seem to get it to line up properly. It looks like the perspective is out. I had it working after inspecting the relationship between the 3d x,y and global x,y which lead me to write the method 'local3dToGlobalXY' shown below but this only worked when the stage was 1024 / 768, strange. I was told that the Sprite2d in the Five3d package does this but can't get that to work either. It has the same results as my 'local3dToGlobalXY' method.

I have put an example up [here](http://jamesjordan.co.nz/five3dtest/) and the project for the example is [here](http://jamesjordan.co.nz/five3dtest/Five3DTest.zip).

The red star is a sprite that is in 3d and the two crosshairs are draw into different scopes. One is drawn into a Sprite2d which is what I was recomended to do and the other is drawn into the root.

Hopefully someone has encountered this or can point out what I have done wrong.

Thanks, J

```
/**
 * ...
 * @author James Jordan
 */
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    private var s3D:Sprite3D;
    private var _scene:Scene3D;
    private var _s:Sprite3D;
    private var star3D:Shape3D;
    private var t:Timer;
    private var crossHairs2D:Sprite;
    private var otherPlane:Sprite2D;
    private var _plane:Sprite3D;
    private var crossHairsRoot:Sprite;
    private var animationPlane:Sprite3D;
    private var crossHairsPlane:Sprite2D;
    private var starsPlane:Sprite3D;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        animationPlane = new Sprite3D();

        starsPlane = new Sprite3D();
        animationPlane.addChild(starsPlane);

        crossHairsPlane = new Sprite2D();
        animationPlane.addChild(crossHairsPlane);

        _scene = new Scene3D();
        _scene.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        _scene.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

        _scene.addChild(animationPlane);

        addChild(_scene);

        star3D = drawStar(starsPlane);
        crossHairs2D = drawGlobalShape(crossHairsPlane, 0xff000, 10);
        crossHairsRoot = drawGlobalShape(root, 0x0000ff, 5);

        t = new Timer(1000, 0);
        t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
        t.start();

    }

    private function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void 
    {
        TweenLite.to(star3D, 1, { x:(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth) - (stage.stageWidth/2), y:(Math.random() * stage.stageHeight) - (stage.stageHeight / 2), z:(Math.random() * 500), onUpdate:onTweenUpdate } );
    }

    private function onTweenUpdate():void 
    {
        var p:Point = local3dToGlobalXY(starsPlane, new Point3D(star3D.x, star3D.y, star3D.z));
        crossHairs2D.x = p.x - stage.stageWidth / 2;
        crossHairs2D.y = p.y -  stage.stageHeight / 2;

        crossHairsRoot.x = p.x;
        crossHairsRoot.y = p.y;
    }

    private function local3dToGlobalXY(_s:Sprite3D, p3d:Point3D):Point 
    {
        var m:Matrix3D = _s.concatenatedMatrix;
        var newP3d:Point3D = m.transformPoint(p3d);
        var globalPoint:Point = _s.local3DToGlobal(new Vector3D(newP3d.x, newP3d.y, newP3d.z));
        return globalPoint;
    }

    private function drawStar(parent:Sprite3D):Shape3D {

        var starShape:Shape3D = new Shape3D();
        DrawingUtils.star(starShape.graphics3D, 5, 30, 20, (45 / 180) * Math.PI, 0xff0000);

        parent.addChild(starShape);

        return starShape;
    }

    private function drawGlobalShape(p:*, c:uint, lineWeight:Number):Sprite 
    {
        var d:Sprite = new Sprite();
        d.graphics.lineStyle(lineWeight, c);
        d.graphics.moveTo( -20, 0);
        d.graphics.lineTo(20, 0);
        d.graphics.moveTo( 0, -20);
        d.graphics.lineTo(0, 20);
        d.graphics.endFill();

        p.addChild(d);

        return d;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your perspective and Z coordinate.  Remove the random Z tween in the TweenLite.to statement and you'll see that they line up perfectly.

What exactly are you trying to do here?  Other than offset the star, the Z param doesn't seem to add anything (scaling based on distance from observer)?

Comment: I am planning on having a circuit / racing car track that will be drawn dynamically then tilted to give perspective. I want items to move around the tilted track then overlay a bitmap on each item so it appears to move around the track but does not scale.

Comment: Here is another example. http://jamesjordan.co.nz/five3dtest/tracktest.swf

The different coloured sprites are on a 2d plane tilted in 3d. I want to map the blue bitmaps to the coloured sprites. It is the same result as my previous example. The perspective is off. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for all the reply's. The random z tween is to illustrate that I can't go from local to global as that is messing it up. I need to be able to move things around in 3d then map that to a global 2d coordinate. Cheers.

Comment: You'll do much better to have it all in 3D, then the perspective, track and actors will all interact appropriately.

Comment: That was my thoughts too but annoyingly the design calls for this implementation.

Comment: If you can control the observer and the target, put them both at the middle of the stage (x and y) and have their z in opposite sides.  I'm not completely familiar with this 3D engine, but by doing this, the alignment of the cross hairs and star will be uniformly offset based on how far they move away from the center.  Using that, you could easily create an algorithm that would adjust the x and y of the cross hairs to compensate for the parallax.

Comment: I can control the observer and the target and center both. That is what I am doing in the crosshair example. I don't know what formular to use to go from 3d to global 2d. I have been reading about Orthogonal Projection but not getting very far. Ideally I was looking for a complete solution so that i could have any number of nested Sprite3D objects all with different transformations and then get the global 2d coordinates. There is a method called concatenatedMatrix in Five3d which seems to work but just falls over in the end as in my examples.

Comment: What you're trying to replicate is accessing the viewing plane of the 3D scene to see where the sprites are in the 2D space.  Think of it as an observer looking at a screen on one side and the sprites run around on the other.  So that projection has to have been made somewhere - take a look in the engine to see if it's available.

Comment: And you might want to look at other 3D frameworks, like www.away3d.com which are a little more robust.

Comment: Thanks @Gone3d. I think I am going to have to move to something else before my boss has me cleaning the toilets full time. I'll give away3d a go tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Away3D is quite nice - it might take you a bit to get use to, but well worth the time.  If you've had any experience with any 3D apps like Maya, Lightwave, etc., it will help, but check out their tutorials and you'll be able to get started in minutes with exactly what you have now.