# Away3d setup (fp10) and drawing paths.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, away3d

I have tried to get a 2D path tilted in 3d then a local3dtoglobal method working for a while now. I was initially using Five3d but [got stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474553/five3d-local3dtoglobal/13475244#comment18445778_13475244). I have moved to Away3D and have quickly discovered it is way over my head. I have made a start but can't even get anything to appear on the stage. Can anyone see if I am on the right route any point out why I can't see anything on the stage.

I am using Away3D fp10 as I read it can draw curves where Away4 fp11 does not have that ability yet.

Thanks

```
package
{
    import away3d.cameras.TargetCamera3D;
    import away3d.containers.View3D;
    import away3d.core.base.Face;
    import away3d.core.base.Mesh;
    import away3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
    import away3d.materials.Material;
    import away3d.materials.WireColorMaterial;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Away3Dfp10Test extends Sprite
    {
        private var _camera:TargetCamera3D;
        private var view:View3D;

        public function Away3Dfp10Test()
        {
             this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        protected function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
            createView();
            createScene();
        }


        private function createView():void
        {
            _camera = new TargetCamera3D();
            _camera.z = -1000;
            view = new View3D();
            view.x = 400;
            view.y = 300;
            view.camera = _camera;
            addChild(view);
        }

        private function createScene():void
        {
            var mesh:Mesh = new Mesh();
            mesh.bothsides = false;
            var material:WireColorMaterial = new WireColorMaterial(0xff0000);
            material.thickness = 10;
            material.color = 0x000000;
            material.wireColor = 0x00ff00;
            mesh.material = material;
            var face:Face = new Face();
            face.moveTo(0, 0, 0);
            face.lineTo(0, 100, 0);
            face.lineTo(100, 100, 0);
            face.lineTo(100, 0, 0);
            face.lineTo(0, 0, 0);
            mesh.addFace(face);
            view.scene.addChild(mesh);
            view.render();
        }

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simplifying a little and try this:

http://away3d.com/tutorials/Setting_Up_Your_Scene

Your createView function might be the problem.

Hang in there and good luck!

this is for the latest version, which I assume you have.

Comment: Some things to help visualize what's going on here:   http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/ComputerGraphics/Projections_Viewpoints.html     http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi03/cse167/lectures/lec10.pdf

Comment: The nice thing with a view plane is that you have a 3D environment projected onto a 2D plane - which is what  you were looking at doing with your other problem